# Javascript Executor not clicking input inside iframe - Selenium

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, selenium, iframe

I had a problem with Javascript executor for selenium when clicking a certain input inside an iframe. The problem happens **only** on **chrome** works fine on IE and FF, don't know why

here's the html file:

```html
<iframe id="iframContainer" ng-src="app/docManagement/upload/iframe/iframe.html" src="app/docManagement/upload/iframe/iframe.html">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="{{dir}}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="uploader.js" type="text/javascript">
<style type="text/css">
</head>
<body class="upload-control">
<div id="drop" class="dragdrop_zone">
<input id="uploader" type="file" multiple="" name="file">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</body>
</html>
 </iframe>
```

and here's my code to click on the element using selenium executor:

```
 int uploadArea = Driver.GetFirstFrameIndex();
       Driver.Upload_File_Generic(FileUpload);
         try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
           Driver.SwitchToFrame(uploadArea);
            Initiate_Driver.ClickJSElement(By.Id(AddREsources_IDs.UploadArea),"Uploader",Messages.ElementValidation.Mandatory);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
       Initiate_Driver.GetOutofFrame();


   public static void SwitchToFrame(int index)
    {
        try
        {

            driver.SwitchTo().Frame(index);
        }
        catch
        {
            Messages.NoSuchFrame(FrameName, validation);
        }
    }
  public static void ClickJS(By by, string ElementName)
    {

        IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

        string _JSCommand = "";

        if (by.ToString().Contains("Id"))
        {
            string ID = by.ToString().Replace("By.Id: ", string.Empty);
            _JSCommand = "document.getElementById('" + ID + "').click();";

        }

        else if (by.ToString().Contains("Name"))
        {
            string Name = by.ToString().Replace("By.Name: ", string.Empty);
            _JSCommand = "document.getElementByName('" + Name + "').click();";
        }


        executor.ExecuteScript(_JSCommand);


    }
```

AGAIN : The proble happens only on chrome but it's working very fine on IE and FF.

Comment: Could you tell us why are you not using `WebElement.click()`??

Comment: the element inside an iframe, also the element to be clicked is a JS element. it's not visible

Comment: Did you tried `WebElement.click()`?? if not try using it, its no matter it is inside any frame or not...if any problem with this then let us know..:)

Comment: yes tried it , the element is a JS element that must be used by a javascript executor

Comment: So when you tried it?? was there any error occured??

Comment: no neither there are errors when using webelement.click nor when using the executor , just the iframe doesn't open to upload a file.

Comment: do you want to click on this browse button to open file upload window??

Comment: instead of click here you can use `.sendKeys("path/to/file")` to upload file...:)

Comment: i want it implemented like that, sauragbh + i found out that as i told you it gave an exception that the element is not visible , click couldn't happen using normal webelement.click

Comment: even the sendkeys , this is a hard-coded solution ??

Comment: Ok  then, try like this `executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.FindElement(By.id("uploader")));` and let me know..:)

Comment: still nothing, no errors or anything just the input doesn't get clicked!!

Comment: maybe it didn't even switch to the iframe ??

Comment: how can i make sure it switched to the right frame ?

Comment: Share your code for switching frame...

Comment: And try once using mouse event as `executor.ExecuteScript('function triggerMouseEvent (node, eventType) {var clickEvent = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');clickEvent.initEvent (eventType, true, true);node.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);}triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], "mouseover");triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], "mousedown");triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], "mouseup");triggerMouseEvent (arguments[0], "click"); ', driver.FindElement(By.id("uploader")));` and let me know..

Comment: i'm getting error too many characters in character  literal

Comment: Ok, provided it as answer, try it and let me know..:)

Comment: What is the exception it is throwing??

Comment: clickEvent is not defined

Comment: Just trying to rearrange the JavaScript string in one line, its correct and tested,  you need to rearrange it.

Comment: why do i have to make it in one line ?